# trying to merge two objects and return merged object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to merge the objects like as below

```
export const extractSourceOfData = (library, isJsonData) => {
  const id = isJsonData ? library?.sourceOfData?.id : library?.sourceOfDataId;
  return { codesStandardsAndGuidelines: id ? [id] : null };
};

export const extractMaterialType = (library, isJsonData) => {
  const id = isJsonData ? library?.materialType.id : library?.materialTypeId;
  return { constructionMaterialTypes: id ? [id] : null };
}
```

and in other component i am importing both above functions and merging like as below

```
import CODE_STANDARD_GUIDELINE, { extractSourceOfData } from '../codeStandardGuideline';
import CONSTRUCTION_MATERIAL_TYPE, { extractMaterialType } from './constructionMaterialType';

export const extractSecondaryIds = {   
  let secondaryIds = Object.assign{{}, ...extractSourceOfData, ...extractMaterialType };
  return secondaryIds
}
```

but getting an error at the spread operator, could any one please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not calling the functions. `extractSourceOfData` is a function, not an object

Comment: sorry i need to get the object from both two functions and make an merged object from those two.

Comment: Either do `{ ...extractSourceOfData(), ...extractMaterialType() }` or `Object.assign{{}, extractSourceOfData(), extractMaterialType() };`

Comment: still it says ',' expected `export const extractSecondaryIds = { 
  let secondaryIds = Object.assign({}, extractSourceOfData(), extractMaterialType());
  return secondaryIds;
}`

Comment: Don't do `Object.assign({}, ...extractSourceOfData(), ...extractMaterialType());`, do `Object.assign({}, extractSourceOfData(), extractMaterialType());`

Comment: sorry still error is same unexpected keyword `const` and with this `export const extractSecondaryIds = { 
  const secondaryIds = Object.assign({}, extractSourceOfData(), extractMaterialType());
  return secondaryIds;
}`

Comment: I am passing but still getting error at here `const secondaryIds` `export const extractSecondaryIds = { 
  const secondaryIds = Object.assign({}, extractSourceOfData(library), extractMaterialType(library));
  return secondaryIds;
}`

Comment: Is `extractSecondaryIds` supposed to be a function or an object? If it's an object, just directly use `export const extractSecondaryIds = Object.assign(.....)`

Comment: it is supposed to be like this `extractSecondaryIds: (library, isJsonData) => {
    const ids = isJsonData ? library?.systems?.map(s => s.id) : library?.systemIds;
    return { libraryAirTypes: ids };
  },`

Comment: This is completely different code. What happened to the merge part?

Comment: sorry i am telling the syntax on how extractsecondaryids should be

Comment: thanks all it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const merged = {...extractSourceOfData(), ...extractMaterialType()};
```